# Back Button is not working properly

Tags: android, titanium-mobile, back-button

I am trying to close the window with back button it does when i press the back button 2nd time. In my code I am running a yql query and inserting data obtained from the query into rows and then adding rows into the table. I can't understand why i need to press back button 2 times please help. Thanks in advance following is my code:

```
var DetailWin = Titanium.UI.currentWindow;
var information = new Array("Company Name: ", "Company Location:", "Position Type:", "Employee            Type:", "Minimum Education:", "Vacancy:", "Gender:", "Salary:");
var var1=Ti.App.lurl;

var rowData = [];

Titanium.Yahoo.yql('select * from html where url="' + var1 + '" and xpath="//p/span" limit 8',     function(e) {

    var results = e.data.span;

    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

        var rss = results[i];
        var rssRow = Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow({
            top : 200,
            height : 45,
            className : 'rssrow'

        });
        var titleLabel = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
            text : information[i] + "     " + rss,
            font : {
                fontSize : 16,
                fontWeight : 'bold'
            },
            width : 'auto',
            top : 5,
            left : 40,
            height : 20,
            color:'black'
        });

        rssRow.add(titleLabel);

        rowData.push(rssRow);
    };
    jobdetail.setData(rowData);

});

var jobdetail = Titanium.UI.createTableView({
    top:'12%',

 });

DetailWin.add(jobdetail);

var backbut = Titanium.UI.createButton({ 
   title:'Back',
   top:'2%',
   width:'20%',
   height:'auto',
   left:'5%'
});

backbut.addEventListener('click', function(){

DetailWin.close();

});
DetailWin.add(backbut);
```

Comment: Did you tried writing an alert inside the click event?

Answer (score 0):

you can handle android back button by adding an event to the window.

```
DetailWin.addEventListener('android:back', function(){

DetailWin.close();

});
```